# Application take a while to start first install

Tags: java, android, performance

community.
I have got this strange problem. When I install my app for the first time, it takes like 5-10 seconds to show up login screen. Before that, it just shows a blank screen.
I've got this code

```
05-31 15:10:27.557 7955-7955/com.example.e3m I/art: Late-enabling Xcheck:jni
05-31 15:10:27.625 7955-7955/com.example.e3m W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.e3m-1/lib/arm
05-31 15:10:35.526 7955-7955/com.example.e3m W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.e3m-1/lib/arm
```

From second to third like it took 8 seconds doing nothing. After this, all works fine. Any hints?

Comment: which build:gradle: version do you use?

Comment: `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"` you mean this?

or this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'`

Comment: no , project build.gradle? and instant run is enable for this project ?

Comment: yes, it is enabled

Comment: i got same problem when instant run is enabled and dont worry about it , it wont occur after publishing an app

Comment: Disabled instant run, problem gone. Thank you.
Any fix to actually use instant run and get rid of that lag?

Comment: I haven't found any and I guess it would have solved in next studio release 2.2 :)